# Executing a set of codes when python GUI is clicked

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, execution

It's my first time trying out Python's GUI and I've decided to go with Tkinter. I have a function in my script which would convert all .txt files in a folder to .xml files. But I would like to create a GUI button which would run my function only if I were to click the button. If I don't click the button, then the files would not be converted at all. How should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the command option of a Button:

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Button

root = Tk()

def func():
    '''Place code to convert files in here'''

    print "Button has been pushed"

Button(text="Push me", command=func).grid()

root.mainloop()
```

`func` will only run when the button is pressed.